# How to find the $\delta$ when one tries to prove a limit of a trigonometric function?

Tags: calculus

For any given trigonometric function how do you prove the limit in the $\epsilon - \delta$ form?
 I've searched the web seems like no one is doing it in the $\epsilon - \delta$ form (I actually did find one example but it was too messy to understand).
I'm basicly stuck on how to find $\delta$

Comment: It depends some on the trigonometric function. If the function is $\sin$ or $\cos$, one can use the identity $|\sin x - \sin y| \leq |x - y|$.

Comment: @Travis even something like $\sin x=0$ when $x \to 0$ how would you do it?

Comment: The above inequality says that for $\sin$, at any point, given any $\epsilon > 0$, you may take $\delta = \epsilon$. Note that, e.g., $\left\vert\frac{d}{dx} \tan x\right\vert$ is unbounded, so there is no analogue of this technique for that function.

Comment: @Travis what did you exactly put instead of the $\sin y$ and $\sin x$? maybe because my example was too zeroish I didnt see it, if it was $\sin 2x + 2$ goes to 3 when x goes to $\pi / 4$

Comment: What do you mean "exactly put instead"? In general, $|\sin kx - \sin ky| \leq k|x - y|$, though you may or may not want to prove this separately.

Comment: @Travis so it means $\sin 2x + 2 \le |2x| + 2$? regarding my previous example thus $\delta$ will be equal to that?

Comment: Perhaps you should modify your original question to include a specific example you'd like worked out. You're more likely to get good replies that way than you are embedding a (to me, somewhat unclear) series of questions in the comments.

Comment: @Travis I tried that but no one answered